# SQL Bulk insert numeric values

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

Hi i have a problem with my sql bulk insert.

I have a .csv file that i'm trying to Bulk insert into a numeric column.

my column looks like this:

```
EnergiKwH (numeric(15,3), null)
```

my values from the .csv file is mainly int number but sometimes there occurs x,xxx values.

my bulk insert looks like this:

```
BULK INSERT Energi
FROM 'c:\1990.csv'
WITH 
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR =';',
    ROWTERMINATOR   = '\n'
);
GO
```

My error is comming on the first x,xxx value.

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 544, column 3 (EnergiKwH).

Please help me.

Comment: ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a' just modify like this and try

Comment: I found it out my problem was that the .csv file saved it with a comma and changing it to a dot made it work.